# What's wrong with this shell command

Tags: shell, busybox

I'm trying to get a shell script written for busybox on one of our embedded devices to work. The line that's causing problems is below and I've included the output of running it in a shell with the -x flag.

```
if [ cut -d : -f 1-3 /sys/class/net/eth0/address | grep -q -i 01:02:03 ]; then
    # Do stuff
fi
```

The output that is given when attempting to run it:

```
# sh -x ./script
+ [ cut -d : -f 1-3 /sys/class/net/eth0/address
sh: missing ]
+ grep -q -i 01:02:03 ]
grep: ]: No such file or directory
+ sync
```

I didn't originally write the script so I don't know when it stopped working. It appears that the command that's being used for the comparison (should return 1 if mac address prefix matches the given sample, 0 otherwise) isn't being run correctly but I don't know why it seems to be trying to seperate the commands out.

Comment: That `if` condition would never have worked. `cut` is a command unto itself, it is not an option for the `[` command. If you want to use a command pipeline as the condition for `if`, just drop the square brackets. And on a non-busybox system, `man test` for further wisdom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `[` as if it were syntax, whereas in the shell it is a command that requires specific arguments to be passed to it.

I think that the fix should be as simple as removing the `[` and corresponding `]` (which is the last argument that `[` expects):

```
if cut -d : -f 1-3 /sys/class/net/eth0/address | grep -q -i 01:02:03; then
```

In the shell, `if` works by looking at the return code of a command, whether it be `[` or any other.

By the way, I don't think that the `-i` option to `grep` is doing anything useful in this case, so you can remove it.

---

Note that your condition can be simplified (thanks to chepner):

```
if grep -q '^01:02:03(:|$)' /sys/class/net/eth0/address; then
```

Match the start of the line, followed by the part you already had, followed by either a colon or the end of the line.

Alternatively:

```
if [ "$(cut -d : -f 1-3 /sys/class/net/eth0/address)" = 01:02:03 ]; then
```

Do a direct string comparison on the output of the cut command, rather than piping to grep.

Comment: The `cut` command itself isn't really necessary, either: `if grep -q '^01:02:03(:|$)' /sys/class/net/eth0/address; then` would be sufficient.

Comment: Or drop `grep` in favor of a simple text comparision: `if [ "$(cut -d : -f 1-3 /sys/class/net/eth0/address)" = 01:02:03 ]; then`.

Comment: @chepner nice suggestions, I've edited them in, thanks.